# How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have array in subdocument like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
    "list" : [
        {
            "a" : 1
        },
        {
            "a" : 2
        },
        {
            "a" : 3
        },
        {
            "a" : 4
        },
        {
            "a" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I filter subdocument for a > 3

My expect result below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
    "list" : [
        {
            "a" : 4
        },
        {
            "a" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to use `$elemMatch` but returns the first matching element in the array

My query:

```
db.test.find( { _id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7") }, { 
    list: { 
        $elemMatch: 
            { a: { $gt:3 } 
            } 
    } 
} )
```

The result return one element in array

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"), "list" : [ { "a" : 4 } ] }
```

and I try to use aggregate with `$match` but not work

```
db.test.aggregate({$match:{_id:ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"), 'list.a':{$gte:5}  }})
```

It's return all element in array

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
    "list" : [
        {
            "a" : 1
        },
        {
            "a" : 2
        },
        {
            "a" : 3
        },
        {
            "a" : 4
        },
        {
            "a" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I filter element in array to get result as expect result?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Using `aggregate` is the right approach, but you need to `$unwind` the `list` array before applying the `$match` so that you can filter individual elements and then use `$group` to put it back together:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id: ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7")}},
    { $unwind: '$list'},
    { $match: {'list.a': {$gt: 3}}},
    { $group: {_id: '$_id', list: {$push: '$list.a'}}}
])
```

outputs:

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
      "list": [
        4,
        5
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

**MongoDB 3.2 Update**

Starting with the 3.2 release, you can use the new [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) aggregation operator to do this more efficiently by only including the `list` elements you want during a `$project`:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id: ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7")}},
    { $project: {
        list: {$filter: {
            input: '$list',
            as: 'item',
            cond: {$gt: ['$$item.a', 3]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

**$and:**
get data between 0-5:

```js
cond: { 
    $and: [
        { $gt: [ "$$item.a", 0 ] },
        { $lt: [ "$$item.a", 5 ] }
]}
```

Comment: Does the aggregation operation modify the document or does it just perform a selection ?

Comment: @Cherif `aggregate` doesn't affect the document itself.

Comment: How would you go about it, If you wanted to publish the result of that query to the client?

Comment: Does this solution utilises the indexes, inside the array elements (if the array element is a document in itself) ? Suppose there is an index on some path in the array element.

Comment: Use `cond: { $eq: ['$$item.a', <value> ] }` to filter elements based on exact equivalent values.

Comment: everywhere I look I see `$filter` references, which is fine for me, but I need to use `$filter` with `$nin` operator and it looks like `cond` does not support it :(
does anybody have any workaround for this?

Comment: @JohnnyHK There is typo in the last condition(closed parantheses)

Answer (score 44):

Above solution works best if multiple matching sub documents are required.
[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) also comes in very use if single matching sub document is required as output

```
db.test.find({list: {$elemMatch: {a: 1}}}, {'list.$': 1})
```

Result:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "list": [{a: 1}]
}
```

Comment: This was the best solution for me. But the second argument works only with primitive types. As i had an object in the array, my solution was: `ShoppingCartModel.findOne({"_id": ctx.params.idCart, "active" : true, products: {$elemMatch : {"products.active" : true}}})`

(I was filtering only the active: true carts and products)

Comment: Nice solution, avoids [the `aggregate(...)` required here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117963/1175496) (even though I love aggregate and I think the aggregate approach is a great answer)

Answer (score 27):

Use [$filter aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

> Selects a subset of the array to return based on the specified
>   condition. Returns an array with only those elements that match the
>   condition. The returned elements are in the original order.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {"list.a": {$gt:3}}}, // <-- match only the document which have a matching element
    {$project: {
        list: {$filter: {
            input: "$list",
            as: "list",
            cond: {$gt: ["$$list.a", 3]} //<-- filter sub-array based on condition
        }}
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Note that if you're using [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), `$filter` cannot be used on the free-tier.

Comment: @SethFalco that doesn't seem to be the case anymore in Oct 2022