# Finding embedded documents in Mongoose ODM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model with array of embedded documents. That was made by design since we often (almost always) query root document together with embedded docs.

```
var SubsetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    name: String,
});

var RootSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    subsets: [SubsetSchema],
});

mongoose.model('collection', RootSchema);
var Root = module.exports = mongoose.model('collection');
```

And finding a single subset document is not a problem using:

```
Root.findOne({'subsets.number': 3}, {_id: 0, 'subsets.$': 1}, ...);
```

However when i need to find multiple subset documents (and in our case using regex) doesn't seem to be possible:

```
Root.find({'subsets.name': /regex/i}, {_id: 0, 'subsets.$': 1}, ...);
```

It gives the following error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "positional operator (subsets.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier",
    "code" : 16352
}
```

How would i do it in this case? Splitting Schema into two collections isn't an option, because that will destroy our performance on other more frequent queries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb)

Comment: @JohnnyHK That is wrong assumption. Please reread my question and the one you suggest as duplicate. Proposed duplicate question is about `aggregation` of already received results, this question is about querying. And while this issue could be solved with aggregation if it was done through driver, in my case (please look closer to the tags and text of question) solution is needed for Mongoose ODM, it simply will not work for me.

Comment: @JohnnyHK BTW, there is a bug on MongoDB JIRA, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9028 and since this is FOSS, i would like to look into this issue once get a little free time.

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature request.  `$` only works for a single matching element so it's working properly.  That's why you have to use an `aggregate` query which works the same for Mongoose as it does for the native driver.

Answer (score 3):

This can be reproduced in the mongo shell:

```
> db.xx.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51610020672afd480ccfb9c4"),
    "name" : "any",
    "subsets" : [
        {
            "number" : 3,
            "name" : "aba"
        },
        {
            "number" : 4,
            "name" : "aka"
        }
    ]
}
> // works as expected:
> db.xx.find({"subsets.number": 3},{_id:0, "subsets.$":1})
{ "subsets" : [ { "number" : 3, "name" : "aba" } ] }
> // does not work
> db.xx.find({"subsets.name": /k/},{_id:0, "subsets.$":1})
error: {
    "$err" : "positional operator (subsets.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier",
    "code" : 16352
}
```

**but this works!**

```
> db.xx.find({"subsets": {$elemMatch:{name:/k/}}},{_id:0, "subsets.$":1})
{ "subsets" : [ { "number" : 4, "name" : "aka" } ] }
```

@AlexKey: I have updated your Jira [SERVER-9028](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9028) accordingly

Comment: I was wrong with my previous comment. It still doesn't work as i would expect. It returns only one element from each root document. In given example please try to use regex `/a/i` This expected to return both elements of `subsets`, but it will return only first one.

Comment: see the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/): The positional $ operator limits the contents of the <array> field that is included in the query results to contain the **first** matching element. - To get all the matched elements out of an array you'll have to use [aggregate()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/)

Comment: `aggregate` doesn't fit my needs. But thanks for consideration.