# MongoDB, select nested arrays fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got a collection were documents have nested arrays, and I would like to select only the lower arrays, is it possible?

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
db.collection.find({},{'family.children.$.toys' :1})
```

document example

```
   {
    "id":1000,
    "name": "Bob",
    "surname":"The Builder",
    "family":{
        "size":2,
        "status": "happy",
        "children":[{
            "name":"Jim",
            "school": "St. Mary",
            "toys":[{
                "name":"Lego"
            },
            {
                "name":"Playstation"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name":"Kate",
            "school": "St. Mary",
            "toys":[{
                "name":"Xbox"
            },
            {
                "name":"Barbie"
            }]
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Expected result (extract only toys list):

```
{
_id:1000,
family:{
    childrens:[{
        toys:[{
            name:Lego
        },
        {
            name:Playstation
        }]
    },
    {
        toys:[{
            name:Xbox,
        },
        {
            name:Barbie
        }]
    }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: One approach would be to use the aggregation framework. I think that would be actually a typical use case for it. The following post will probably guide you a bit more in the direction of a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb

Comment: Can you at least try to post valid JSON data?

Comment: He only needs $project from the aggregation framework, which is also available for find().

Comment: @user3100115 Now it should be ok

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({},{'id':1, 'family.children.toys' :1, '_id':0})
```

Sample output:

```
{
        "id" : 1000,
        "family" : {
                "children" : [
                        {
                                "toys" : [
                                        {
                                                "name" : "Lego"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "name" : "Playstation"
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                                "toys" : [
                                        {
                                                "name" : "Xbox"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "name" : "Barbie"
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: This works, and it was pretty simple! I was sure that I had already tried it, so I posted the question :D. Thanks

Comment: this works.
How can I add one more field "_id" of each "toy" along with its "name" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with aggregation. You use the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to return only the `toys` field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{ 
    "$project": { 
        "family.childrens": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$family.children",
                "as": "f", 
                "in": { "toys": "$$f.toys" }
            }
        }
     }}
 ])
```

Comment: The accepted answer looks more direct, there is any performance reason why we should use this aggregation framework version?

Comment: @MQ87 No the accepted answer is the best way to do this here(I even upvoted the answer). I added this answer so you know because sometimes aggregation is the only way.