# Spring Boot Data and MongoDB - Filter Subdocument Array Query

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb

I am attempting to use Spring to Query a Mongo repository and filter an array subdocument.  I have referenced [how to filter array in subdocument with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb/), but was wondering if there was a more appropriate or java structured method to do so using Spring.

I am currently using the shorthand repository interface notation, but I am getting back the complete document with the array not filtered.

**PersonRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository <Person, String> {
    List<Person> findByAddressZipCode(@Param("zip") int zip);
}
```

**Person.java**

```
@Document
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Address> address;
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address {
    private int zip;
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
{
 "firstName":"George",
 "lastName":"Washington",
 "address":[{
     "zip":"12345"
  },{
     "zip":"98765"
  },{
     "zip":"12345"
  }]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
 "firstName":"George",
 "lastName":"Washington",
 "address":[{
     "zip":"12345"
  },{
     "zip":"12345"
  }]
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
{
 "firstName":"George",
 "lastName":"Washington",
 "address":[{
     "zip":"12345"
  },{
     "zip":"98765"
  },{
     "zip":"12345"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, In Spring Data such kind of queries is not `trivial`.

**Bad news:**
Spring Data Repository does not have solution for `MongoDB Aggregation`. So, you cannot implement in MongoRepository any method to do so, like `aggregateBy...`

**Good news:**
Spring Data provides `MongoTemplate` class which allows you to execute complex queries, like you would do in standard MongoDB shell.

So, as you just want to `exclude` subdocument that does not match some condition, we need to define the aggregate `pipelines`.

**I assume:**

```
zip codes are Numeric (In your example is string)
And, to exclude subdocument, we filter by `zip`
There is no any other filter
```

MongoDB aggregation would be:

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$address"},
    {$match: {"address.zip": 12345}},
    {$group: { _id: { "firstName":"$firstName", "lastName":"$lastName", _id:"$_id" }, address: { $push: "$address" } } },
    {$project: {_id:0, "firstName":"$_id.firstName", "lastName":"$_id.lastName", "address": "$address"}}
])
```

If all filters success, we got:

```
[ 
    {
        "address" : [ 
            {
                "zip" : 12345
            }, 
            {
                "zip" : 12345
            }
        ],
        "firstName" : "George",
        "lastName" : "Washington"
    }
]
```

---

Now, in Spring Data way, you need add some changes in your project:

First, find your `mongo-config.xml` where you need to add:

```
<!-- Define the mongoDbFactory with your database Name  -->
<mongo:db-factory uri="mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/db"/>

<!-- Define the MongoTemplate  -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

`MongoTemplate` is the central class of the Spring’s MongoDB support providing feature sets to interact with the database. The template `...` provides a mapping between your **domain objects** and **MongoDB documents**. [More info](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template)

Second, in your `@Service` class, add following code to be loaded in `@PostConstruct`

```
@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

...

public List<Person> findByAddressZipCode(int zip) {

    List<AggregationOperation> list = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();
    list.add(Aggregation.unwind("address"));
    list.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("address.zip").is(zip)));
    list.add(Aggregation.group("firstName", "lastName").push("address").as("address"));
    list.add(Aggregation.project("firstName", "lastName", "address"));
    TypedAggregation<Person> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Person.class, list);
    return mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, Person.class, Person.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

**Note:** Both, `Person` and `Address` should have default empty constructor!

Comment: Thank you very much Valijon.  This did work very nicely for my use case, and figured the Aggregation would be the most appropriate method.  Do you have any other recommendations for a more easily readable method or using an additional framework that would not require extensive knowledge of the mongo shell language?

Comment: Well, Spring Data is the most "readable" framework nowadays. It is very usefull for easy "queries" like by defining methods in MongoRepository. It maps "automatically" MongoDB documents to your POJO class. Also, provides QueryDSL query builder (for agregations, more complex query). Other frameworks, like native MongoDB driver requires extensive knowledge as shell command line. In our project, we use Spring Data for MongoDB queries.

Comment: Thank you very much Valijon. This was very helpful