# MongoDB nested array search using $map

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have collection which contains nested array. I need to fetch the data based on below condition:

```
empId : 19107
address.country: "AUS"
group.primaryGroup.primary:"Y"
group.subGroup.primarySubGroup.primary : "Y"
```

Input:

```
{
    "empId": "19107",
    "address": [
        {
            "street": "no.12 wilson street",
            "country":"AUS"
        },
        {
            "description": "No.32 watson street",
            "country":"CAN"
        }
    ],
    "mobile": 2387468238,
    "group": [
        {
            "groupId": 75227,
            "primaryGroup": [
                {
                    "primary": "Y"
                },
                {
                    "primary": "N"
                }
            ],
            "subGroup": [
                {
                    "subGroupId": 123,
                    "primarySubGroup": [
                        {
                            "primary": "Y"
                        },
                        {
                            "primary": "N"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "subGroupId": 234,
                    "primarySubGroup": [
                        {
                            "primary": "N"
                        },
                        {
                            "primary": "Y"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the output as below:

```
{
    "empId": "19107",
    "address": [
        {
            "street": "no.12 wilson street",
            "country":"AUS"
        }
    ],
    "mobile": 2387468238,
    "group": [
        {
            "groupId": 75227,
            "primaryGroup": [
                {
                    "primary": "Y"
                }
            ],
            "subGroup": [
                {
                    "subGroupId": 123,
                    "primarySubGroup": [
                        {
                            "primary": "Y"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "subGroupId": 234,
                    "primarySubGroup": [
                        {
                            "primary": "Y"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below given the query which I tried:

```
[{"$match" : {"empId":90, "address" : {"$elemMatch": {"country": {"$eq":"AUS"}}}, "group" :{"$elemMatch" : {"primaryGroup": {"$elemMatch" : {"primary": {"$eq": "Y"}}}, "subGroup" : {"$elemMatch" : { "primarySubGroup" : { "$elemMatch": {"primary" : {"$eq" : "Y"}}}}}}}}}, {"$project": {"empId":1, "mobile":1, "address": {"$filter" : {"input": "$address", "as": "d", "cond": {"$eq": ["$$d.country", "AUS"]}}}  , "group" : {"$map": {"input": "$group", "as" : "v", "in": {"primaryGroup": {"$filter": {"input": "$$v.primaryGroup", "as": "vp", "cond": {"$eq": ["$$vp.primary", "Y"]}}}}}}, "subGroup": {"$map" : {"input": "$group", "as" : "n", "in": {"primarySubGroup" : {"$filter": {"input": "$$n.group", "as" : "mp", "cond": {"$eq": ["$$mp.primarySubGroup.primary", "830090"]}}}}}}  }}]
```

I am new to mongoDB. I tried the below approach ([Spring data Match and Filter Nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471800/spring-data-match-and-filter-nested-array)) but I am facing some issue in nested array fetch. 
ex: Instead of groupId, I need to compare the primaryGroup in $map which is present in group field.

Could you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the approach that you've tried and let us know where you are stuck ?

Comment: I have updated the query which I tried. I am not getting, how to make filter in subgroup and get the result inside group. Could help me correcting the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below query.

Couple of things I've changed.

1.No `$elemMatch` is required for single criteria. Use dot notation instead.

2.Move the subgroup's `$map` inside group's `$map` operator.

```
[
  {"$match":{
    "empId":"19107",
    "address.country":"AUS",
    "group.primaryGroup.primary":"Y",
    "group.subGroup.primarySubGroup.primary":"Y"
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "empId":1,
    "mobile":1,
    "address":{"$filter":{"input":"$address","as":"d","cond":{"$eq":["$$d.country","AUS"]}}},
    "group":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$group",
        "as":"v",
        "in":{
          "groupId":"$$v.groupId",
          "primaryGroup":{"$filter":{"input":"$$v.primaryGroup","as":"vp","cond":{"$eq":["$$vp.primary","Y"]}}},
          "subGroup":{
            "$map":{
              "input":"$$v.subGroup",
              "as":"n",
              "in":{
                "subGroupId":"$$n.subGroupId",
                "primarySubGroup":{"$filter":{"input":"$$n.primarySubGroup","as":"mp","cond":{"$eq":["$$mp.primary","Y"]}}}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the query but it is not returning any result. In your query, I changed the empId to 19107 and tried but I didn't received any data. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yw. Fixed and verified.

Comment: I am facing a small issue in the query which return empty if it is not finding any match in primarySubGroup array.ex:  "subGroup" : [{
 "subGroupId" : 123,
 "primarySubGroup" : [{"primary" : "N"},{"primary" : "N"}
 ]},{
 "subGroupId" : 234,
 "primarySubGroup" : [{"primary" : "N"},{"primary" : "Y"}
 ]}
]
In the above field 123 is not matching the criteria so I shouldn't get it. I should get only 234 but I am getting 123 array with primarySubGroup empty. Can you suggest me how to fix it.

Comment: I see. Is it only applicable to primarySubGroup ? What about primaryGroup ?

Comment: Yes, Actually In subGroup[] array, subGroup[0].primarySubGroup criteria matches then only I need to take subGroup[0] otherwise I don't need it.

Comment: You can try `"subGroup":{
            "$map":{
              "input":{"$filter":{"input":"$$v.subGroup","as":"np","cond":{"$in":["Y", "$$np.primarySubGroup.primary",]}}},
              "as":"n",
              "in":{
                "subGroupId":"$$n.subGroupId",
                "primarySubGroup":{"$filter":{"input":"$$n.primarySubGroup","as":"mp","cond":{"$eq":["$$mp.primary","Y"]}}}
              }
            }
          }`  in 3.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165714/discussion-between-praveen-d-and-veeram).

Comment: could you please help me with this below changes:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165714/discussion-between-praveen-d-and-veeram

Comment: Please create a new question with the details from chat