# Mongo Template find element in a list inside of a document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

This is a document I want to search. Collection is `CustmObjects`. This is one `CustomObject`

```
{
    "id" : "id_1",
    "name" : "name_1";
    "additionalData" : [
        {
             "additionalDataId" : "id_1_1",
             "additionalDataName" : "name_1_1",
             "longText" : "A long story about..."  
        },
        {
             "additionalDataId" : "id_1_2",
             "additionalDataName" : "name_1_2",
             "longText" : "A longer story about danger..."  
        },
        {
             "additionalDataId" : "id_1_3",
             "additionalDataName" : "name_1_3",
             "longText" : "A longer story about danger and courage"  
        },
    ]       
}
```

To retrieve  a document with name *name_1* is easy.

```
final nameToSearchBy = "name_1";

Query query = new Query();
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("name").is(nameToSearchBy);
query.addCriteria(criteria);
mongoTemplate.findOne(query, CustomObject.class, "CUSTOM_OBJECTS_COLLECTION");
```

Now my question. How to retrieve `additionalData` with name `"id_1_2"`? I do not need to retrieve the whole document, only an **entry** in the array.

Of course, I can retrive a whole document and iterate through its `additionalData` values in java program. But I want to delegate this job to database server.

I tried

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("name").is("name_1").and("additionalData.additionalDataName").is("name_1_2")),
        Aggregation.project("additionalData"),
);
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "CustmObjects", Object.class);
```

It returns all elements of the array. I need only one matching element.

### Update

This is what I want to do
[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

```
db.find({shapes: {"$elemMatch": {name: "name_1_2"}}}, ... )
```

As I understand, what the second part is projection to select fields. I need all the fields from array element.

```
{"shapes.color": 1}
```

The second link
[Spring data Match and Filter Nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471800/spring-data-match-and-filter-nested-array)

The **result** I want to get is this

```
{
     "additionalDataId" : "id_1_2",
     "additionalDataName" : "name_1_2",
     "longText" : "A long story about..."  
}
```

is more comlex, it has array inside of element which is inside of array.
Please, I need something more simple and working.

Comment: can you provide more details : Do you want to retrieve whole documents where at least one array element have  "additionalDataName" : "name_1_2", or do you want to ertrieve only entry of array that matches that condition?

Comment: here's the query in js :
db.collection.find(
{  name: "name_1"},
{
  _id: 0,  
  additionalData: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "additionalDataName": "name_1_2"
    }
  }
})

Comment: open a new question : "how to translate this in java / spring boot?" Cannot answer here.

Comment: Please, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013224/mongo-db-request-in-java-spring-data-mongo