# How to return match document by using $in operator for array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

may I know how can I use `$in` operator for array of object? and only return match document as result?

This is what I have tried so far but I still not able to get what I want.

Let's say I have set of documents look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56824417fa32883c0335ce61"),
    "company_name" : "Pentagon",
    "deal_details" : [
        {
            "deals_name" : "hello",
            "deals_tag" : ["A","B","C"],
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
        },
    {
            "deals_name" : "Hola",
            "deals_tag" : ["E","F","G"],
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
        },
    ],
  "_id" : ObjectId("54824417fa32983c0335ce61"),
    "company_name" : "Oreo",
    "deal_details" : [
        {
            "deals_name" : "Bye",
            "deals_tag" : ["B"],
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
        },
    {
            "deals_name" : "Ciao",
            "deals_tag" : ["H","I","J"],
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
        },
    ]
}
```

and I do this

```
User.find({
  'deal_details.deals_tags': {
    $in: ["B"]
  }
 }
}, {'deal_details':1}).exec(function(err, deal) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
  res.status(200).send(deal);
});
```

what I **expect** from `deal` is

```
            {
                "deals_name" : "hello",
                "deals_tag" : ["A","B","C"],
                "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
            },
             {
                "deals_name" : "Bye",
                "deals_tag" : ["B"],
                "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
            }
```

**however** I get this instead

```
            {
                "deals_name" : "hello",
                "deals_tag" : ["A","B","C"],
                "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
            },
            {
                "deals_name" : "Hola",
                "deals_tag" : ["E","F","G"],
                "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
            },
             {
                    "deals_name" : "Bye",
                    "deals_tag" : ["B"],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
             },
             {
            "deals_name" : "Ciao",
            "deals_tag" : ["H","I","J"],
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c69da8a1f60804064abf0f")
             }
```

So can I know is there a way to only return **only matched document**? 
your help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

```
User.aggregate([{$unwind: '$deal_details'}, 
                {$match: {'deal_details.deals_tag': 'B'}}, 
                {$project: {deal_details: 1, _id: 0}}])
```

Comment: Hi @zangw thanks for your reply, may I know is it possible to use $in in $match in order to match more document? like ['B','H'] and then return match document

Comment: @JohnLim, yes, you can do that as `{$match: {'deal_details.deals_tag': {$in: ['B', 'H']}}}`

Answer (score 2):

To find elements with specific value in array in sub Document (it's your case) and to filter the result, you shoul use the aggregation framework. It's impossible with a simple find document.

You can see an example with your problem here : [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb)