# Mongoose Query to filter an array and Populate related content

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query the property that is an array of both reference to another schema and some additional data. For better clarification, here's the schema:

```
    var orderSchema = new Schema({
        orderDate: Date,
        articles: [{
            article: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Article'
            },
            quantity: 'Number'
        }]
    }),
    Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

While I managed to successfully query the reference, i.e.:

```
Order.find({}).populate('articles.article', null, {
    price: {
        $lte: 500
    }
}).exec(function(err, data) {
    for (var order of data) {
        for (var article of order.articles) {
            console.log(article);
        }
    }
});
```

I have some issues querying the `quantity` attribute, i.e. this doesn't work:

```
Order.find({}).where({
    'articles.quantity': {
        $gte: 5
    }
}).populate('articles.article', null, {
    /*price: {
        $lte: 500
    }*/
}).exec(function(err, data) {
    for (var order of data) {
        for (var article of order.articles) {
            console.log(article);
        }
    }
});
```

Is it even possible to base the query on `quantity`? And if so, what would be the best approach?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

The problem is, the result is either a complete array, or nothing (see updated question). I want to get only those records that have quantity more or the same as 5. With your (and mine) approach I get either no records at all (if I set $gte: 5001) or both records (if I set $gte:5000)

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('56fe76c12f7174ac5018054f'),
    "orderDate": ISODate('2016-04-01T13:25:21.055Z'),
    "articles": [
        {
            "article": ObjectId('56fe76c12f7174ac5018054b'),
            "quantity": 5000,
            "_id": ObjectId('56fe76c12f7174ac50180551')
        },
        {
            "article": ObjectId('56fe76c12f7174ac5018054c'),
            "quantity": 1,
            "_id": ObjectId('56fe76c12f7174ac50180552')
        }
    ],
    "__v": 1
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the query `articles.quantity` doesn't work? Is there any output you can add to the question?

Comment: I removed the bad answer. Can you check that the query part does return you the desired results, without populating? If it returns you the whole array then there is a problem in the query, as populate works on the query result.

Comment: Is your problem the same as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb) ?

Comment: @MarioTrucco It "sort of" is, except the concept here is that some of the data resides in another collection and there is a desire to `.populate()` and "filter" on those results as well. I almost put a hold ( in fact I did, but removed ) as this does in fact have elements of "two" long standing answers, but actually in it's own "unique" way. So IMHO it kind of stands on it's own.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to "project" the match here since all the MongoDB query does is look for a "document" that has *"at least one element"* that is *"greater than"* the condition you asked for.

So filtering an "array" is not the same as the "query" condition you have.

A simple "projection" will just return the "first" matched item to that condtion. So it's probably not what you want, but as an example:

```
Order.find({ "articles.quantity": { "$gte": 5 } })
    .select({ "articles.$": 1 })
    .populate({
        "path": "articles.article",
        "match": { "price": { "$lte": 500 } }
    }).exec(function(err,orders) {
       // populated and filtered twice
    }
)
```

That "sort of" does what you want, but the problem is really going to be that will only ever return at most **one** element within the `"articles"` array.

To do this properly you need `.aggregate()` to filter the array content. Ideally this is done with MongoDB 3.2 and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). But there is also a special way to `.populate()` here:

```
Order.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "artciles.quantity": { "$gte": 5 } } },
        { "$project": {
            "orderdate": 1,
            "articles": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$articles",
                    "as": "article",
                    "cond": {
                       "$gte": [ "$$article.quantity", 5 ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "__v": 1
        }}
    ],
    function(err,orders) {
        Order.populate(
            orders.map(function(order) { return new Order(order) }),
            {
                "path": "articles.article",
                "match": { "price": { "$lte": 500 } }
            },
            function(err,orders) {
                // now it's all populated and mongoose documents
            }
        )
    }
)
```

So what happens here is the actual "filtering" of the array happens within the `.aggregate()` statement, but of course the result from this is no longer a "mongoose document" because one aspect of `.aggregate()` is that it can "alter" the document structure, and for this reason mongoose "presumes" that is the case and just returns a "plain object".

That's not really a problem, since when you see the `$project` stage, we are actually asking for all of the same fields present in the document according to the defined schema. So even though it's just a "plain object" there is no problem "casting" it back into an mongoose document.

This is where the `.map()` comes in, as it returns an array of converted "documents", which is then important for the next stage.

Now you call [`Model.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) which can then run the further "population" on the "array of mongoose documents".

The result then is finally what you want.

---

### MongoDB older versions than 3.2.x

The only things that really change here are the aggregation pipeline, So that is all that needs to be included for brevity.

**MongoDB 2.6** - Can filter arrays with a combination of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/). The result is a "set" but that is not a problem when mongoose creates an `_id` field on all sub-document arrays by default:

```
    [
        { "$match": { "artciles.quantity": { "$gte": 5 } } },
        { "$project": {
            "orderdate": 1,
            "articles": {
                "$setDiffernce": [
                   { "$map": {
                      "input": "$articles",
                      "as": "article",
                      "in": {
                         "$cond": [
                             { "$gte": [ "$$article.price", 5 ] },
                             "$$article",
                             false
                         ]
                      }
                   }},
                   [false]
                ]
            },
            "__v": 1
        }}
    ],
```

Older revisions of than that must use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

```
    [
        { "$match": { "artciles.quantity": { "$gte": 5 } }},
        { "$unwind": "$articles" },
        { "$match": { "artciles.quantity": { "$gte": 5 } }},
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "orderdate": { "$first": "$orderdate" },
          "articles": { "$push": "$articles" },
          "__v": { "$first": "$__v" }
        }}
    ],
```

### The $lookup Alternative

Another alternate is to just do everything on the "server" instead. This is an option with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) of MongoDB 3.2 and greater:

```
Order.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "artciles.quantity": { "$gte": 5 } }},
        { "$project": {
            "orderdate": 1,
            "articles": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$articles",
                    "as": "article",
                    "cond": {
                       "$gte": [ "$$article.quantity", 5 ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "__v": 1
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$articles" },
        { "$lookup": {
            "from": "articles",
            "localField": "articles.article",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "articles.article"
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$articles.article" },
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "orderdate": { "$first": "$orderdate" },
          "articles": { "$push": "$articles" },
          "__v": { "$first": "$__v" }
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "orderdate": 1,
            "articles": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$articles",
                    "as": "article",
                    "cond": {
                       "$lte": [ "$$article.article.price", 500 ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "__v": 1
        }}
    ],
    function(err,orders) {

    }
)
```

And though those are just plain documents, it's just the same results as what you would have got from the `.populate()` approach. And of course you can always go and "cast" to mongoose documents in all cases again if you really must.

### The "shortest" Path

This really goes back to the orginal statement where you basically just "accept" that the "query" is not meant to "filter" the array content. The `.populate()` can happilly do so becuse it's just another "query" and is stuffing in "documents" by convenience.

So if you really are not saving "bucketloads" of bandwith by the removal of additional array members in the orginal document array, then just `.filter()` them out in post processing code:

```
Order.find({ "articles.quantity": { "$gte": 5 } })
    .populate({
        "path": "articles.article",
        "match": { "price": { "$lte": 500 } }
    }).exec(function(err,orders) {
        orders = orders.filter(function(order) {
            order.articles = order.articles.filter(function(article) {
                return (
                    ( article.quantity >= 5 ) &&
                    ( article.article != null )
                )
            });
            return order.aricles.length > 0;
        })

        // orders has non matching entries removed            
    }
)
```

Comment: The code where the solution uses `"$filter"` has some errors, namely: `Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`

Comment: @uglycode That means you don't have MongoDB 3.2 or greater. The other content is for you.

Comment: Thanks. Still, I believe there are some issues with `}` symbols, not closing correctly or too many... I get the error: `  91,17: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 85 and instead saw '{'.` I think this is in all of the possible solutions.

Comment: @uglycode Pretty simple syntax errors. Corrected. Sorry I was't completely syntatically correct by missing a closing bracket or two when explaining such an advanced concept. And typing directly into the question here rather than an IDE. Some might actually say "thankyou" for taking the time to explain the concepts.

Comment: I didn't want to come off as ungrateful, I was merely stating that there were syntax errors in the code, if someone else might find this thread and copy/paste your solution. I am of course grateful for your effort and time. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
exports.getStudentBy = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // get search_criteria from query parameter
    // build a query object with it
    // send data to the frontend

    const { search_field, search_value } = req.query;

    const queryObj = {};

    if (search_field !== '' && search_value !== '') {
      queryObj[search_field] = search_value;
    }

    const student = await Student.find(queryObj);
```