# mongodb filter arrays inside each property

Tags: node.js, mongodb

supposes i have the following collection:

```
[{
    "_id": "124124214124",
    "providers": {
        "stackoverflow": {
            "id": 123,
            "results": [{
                "result": 1
            }, {
                "result": 2
            }, {
                "result": 3
            }, {
                "result": 4
            }, {
                "result": 5
            }, {
                "result": 6
            }, {
                "result": 7
            }, {
                "result": 8
            }]
        },
        "stackoverflow": {
            "id": 123,
            "results": [{
                "result": 1
            }, {
                "result": 2
            }, {
                "result": 3
            }, {
                "result": 4
            }, {
                "result": 5
            }, {
                "result": 6
            }, {
                "result": 7
            }, {
                "result": 8
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    "_id": "ghfghfgh",
    "providers": {
        "stackoverflow": {
            "id": 123,
            "results": [{
                "result": 1
            }, {
                "result": 2
            }, {
                "result": 3
            }, {
                "result": 4
            }, {
                "result": 5
            }, {
                "result": 6
            }, {
                "result": 7
            }, {
                "result": 8
            }]
        },
        "stackoverflow": {
            "id": 123,
            "results": [{
                "result": 1
            }, {
                "result": 2
            }, {
                "result": 3
            }, {
                "result": 4
            }, {
                "result": 5
            }, {
                "result": 6
            }, {
                "result": 7
            }, {
                "result": 8
            }]
        }
    }
}]
```

I am trying to return the all the results bigger then 3 for example.
How can i accomplish this?

I tried doing it with `$elemMatch` but from what i understood it is not possible.

This question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb) answer because in this question i need to do the query for each property in an object.

Comment: do you mean all documents with a result with value > 3, or all documents with a results array with > 3 elements?

Comment: actually this is different. my question is about filtering in array in each property of a object

Comment: @robjwilkins all array elements that are > 3