# Basic Mongo DB Find example

Tags: mongodb

Below is a screenshot of my mongo db collection.

i want to be able to find all record where the artist is Vónia Fernandes

after reading online i was able to get all entrys from 2008 with

```
db.eurovision.find({},{2008:1})
```

The screen show below returns nothing. Ive also tried putting Artist in quotes
[image]

Comment: Try `db.eurovision.find({"2008.Artist":"Vónia Fernandes"})` More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Comment: This returned the entire collection

Comment: You need to use `$filter` aggregation if you need to return all the matching entries for `Vónia Fernandes` in `2008.Artist` embedded array. Something like `db.eurovision.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         artists: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$2008.Artist",
               as: "artist",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$artist.Artist", "Vónia Fernandes" ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.eurovision.find({2008: {$elemMatch: {Artist:'Vonia Fernandes'}}})
```