# Mongo $aggregate and $filter not working

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregation-framework

I've a problem while filtering an array of values of a specific document.
The collection name is lists and I've a document with 'fields' as _id.
Here is a part of document:

```
{
"_id" : "fields",
"values" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "sku",
        "dt" : "text"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "title",
        "dt" : "text"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "desc",
        "dt" : "text"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "brand",
        "dt" : "text"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "cur",
        "dt" : "text"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "l_img",
        "dt" : "text"
    }, 
    .....
    ]
}
```

I need to retrieve an array of strings that match a specified Regular Expression.

This is my query:

```
db.lists.aggregate([
{
    $match : { _id: "fields"}
},
{
    $project: {
       values: {
          $filter: {
             input: "$values",
             as: "val",
             cond: { "$$val.name" : { $regex: /sk/i } }
          }
       }
    }
 }
]);
```

and this is the error I get:

*assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$$val.name'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed*

I tried the situation of the post [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb) and it works fine, but implemented for my needs and document structure does not. Where I'm doing wrong??

The oldest syntax (previous 3.2 version) works fine:

```
db.lists.aggregate(
{ $match: {_id: "fields"}},
{ $unwind: '$values'},
{ $match: {'values.name': { $regex: /sk/i }}},
{ $group: {_id: '$_id', values: {$push: '$values.name'}}})
```

In fact I get:

```
{ "_id" : "fields", "values" : [ "sku", "sku_parent", "skin_type", "skin_tone" ] }
```

My mongo db version is 3.2.9.

Comment: Did you try to put only one $ in the $$val.name

Comment: $regex is not supported expression in filter, try with other expressions it works

Comment: Hi AshokGK, the problem seems not to be the regex: see my following post

Comment: Hi israel.zinc, I got the same error using the syntax you suggested: **"$val.name" : { $regex: /sk/i }**  - assert: command failed: _{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$val.name'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed_

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems not to be the regex:

```
db.lists.aggregate([
{
   $match : { _id: "fields"}
},
{
   $project: {
      values: {
        $filter: {
           input: "$values",
           as: "val",
           cond: { "$$val.name" : "sku" }
        }
     }
   }
}
]);
```

*assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$$val.name'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed*

Comment: The problem is with your `cond`. Try   `cond: {$eq:["$$val.name",  "sku" ]}` and regex is not supported in `$project`. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947 & https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8892

Comment: Thanks, I'll relay on the old syntax then! I need the regex.