# Mongodb - try to further filter to the child array of document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data like this

```json
{
   "_id":1,
   "v_name":"Hair Patch in Delhi",
   "v_url":"https://www.testurlvideo.com",
   "v_comments":[
      {
         "user":"Kush Khurana",
         "comment":"Awesome Video"
      },
      {
         "user":"Nikhil",
         "comment":"Keep up the good videos"
      },
      {
         "user":"Kush Khurana",
         "comment":"Very good and Awesome Video"
      }
   ]
}
```

But I want the data like this below

```json
{
   "_id":1,
   "v_comments":[
      {
         "user":"Nikhil",
         "comment":"Keep up the good videos"
      }
   ]
}
```

What query I need in MongoDB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You only need `$filter` to select the subdocuments in array and `$project` to output only fields you want.

Check this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "v_comments": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$v_comments",
          "as": "arr",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$arr.user",
              "Nikhil"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

First `$match` by `_id` (optional if you want look for only in one specific document).
And then `$project` to show the field `v_comments` filtered by those object whose `user` is `Nikhil`.
Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OFsZkOUuANI)

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: following methods only return **one** array element.

---

```
var query = { "_id": 1, "v_comments.user": "Nikhil" }
var project =   { "v_comments.$": 1 }

db.collection.find( query, project )
```

**Explanation**

- Syntax: `db.collection.find(query, projection)`
- It projects only the array element that matches the query.

Another simple one:

```
db.collection.find(
    { "_id": 1 },
    { "v_comments": { "$elemMatch": { "user": "Nikhil" } } }
)
```

### [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Fka3EUJLlC)

Comment: For information, The `$` and `$elemMatch` will return only single matched element form array field, as per OP's question, single user can have multiple comments!