# How to query and filter multiple documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with 80 documents, each document looks like the one below. Is there a way that I can search through each document's "data" array and find any objects that have a "color" of 'red', all in one query to the mongodb database? or would I have to make 80 different queries to the mongodb database to do this?

```
{
  _id: 'j3k1jrh123h42',
  data: [
    {name: 'ben', color: 'red'},
    {name: 'tom', color: 'blue'},
    {name: 'will', color: 'red'},
    {name: 'jack', color: 'red'},
    {name: 'bob', color: 'yellow'}
  ],
  class: '8A',
  lastUpdate: '12-05-2021'
}
```

Comment: see similar question [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb)

Comment: I don't think that question is asking about querying multiple documents though

Comment: your question is not clear, okay for multiple conditions you can use $elemMatch operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can get records that have an element with `color: red` by

`Model.find({"data.color": "red"})`

If you want to filter the data array such that it only has elements with `color: red`

```
Model.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "data.color": "red"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        data: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$data",
                as: "doc",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$doc.color", "red"] }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Is there any way to get an array of just the {name: 'jack', color: 'red'} objects, as opposed to getting an array of documents that only contain the filtered data?

Comment: You can use "$unwind", "$replaceRoot" for that.
Add the following stages to the existing pipeline.
`{ "$unwind": "$data"  }, { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }  }`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do you can use aggregtion with [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), or with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find easy all documents containing any elements
with data.color: red via $match , but if you want the result to contain only the color: red element arrays you can use   $filter  or $unwind/$match