# [pymongo]: Find items in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Here is one of the document from which i would like get all the child.item ('Toy1','Toy2' etc) in a list.

```
{
    _id: 'Toy',
    name: 'Toyname',
    child: [
      { item: 'Toy1', isActive: '1', Type: 'New' },
      { item: 'Toy2', isActive: '2', Type: 'Old' }
    ]
  }
```

I have tried

```
pipeline = [
   {
      "$match": {
         "_id": "Toy",
         "child.isActive": '1'
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind":
         "$child"
    },
]
list(DB.Category.aggregate(pipeline))
[{'_id': 'Toy', 'name': 'Toyname', 'child': {'item': 'Toy1', 'isActive': 1, 'Type': 'New'}}, {'_id': 'Toy', 'name': 'Toyname', 'child': {'item': 'Toy2', 'isActive': 2,
'Type': 'Old'}}]
```

And tried this on dbshell

```
#> db.Category.find({name:"Toyname",child:{$elemMatch:{Type:"New"} }})
[
  {
    _id: 'Toy',
    name: 'Toyname',
    child: [
      { item: 'Toy1', isActive: '1', Type: 'New' },
      { item: 'Toy2', isActive: '2', Type: 'Old' }
    ]
  }
]
```

But as you can see it gives me both the items from the array. I am using pymongo 4.0.1.

Expecting a list as o/p which fulfilled match criteria like Type:'New' in $match should return 'Toy1' and isActive:'2' should return 'Toy2'.
I hope i am able to put my requirement clearly.

Comment: it would be helpful if you post expected result in JSON format.

Comment: I want all the items which falls under Type:'new' or isActive:'1' in a list.

Comment: Look at the duplicate question, [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb), you can use $filter expression operator and for c ondition use $and operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in a `find` query. (Be careful because `$elemMatch` only returns one object from the array)

You can use this query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "_id": "Toy"
},
{
  "child": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "isActive": "1"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [https://mongoplayground.net/p/du7FTnvlW7C]

But also check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/izOUTspwx8n) where there are two `isActive: "1"` and only one is returned.

2. Using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in an aggregate query (also you can use `$match`,`$unwind` and `$group` together but I think using `$filter` is a better way).

So using `aggregate` you can try this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "Toy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "child": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$child",
          "as": "c",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": ["$$c.isActive","1"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ij35vIM3jqg)

And using `$unwind` you need [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PCeF2xiSnq3) which I think is too heavy: two `$match`, an `$unwind` and a `$group`... when you can only use `$filter`.