# get specfic objects from array inside array of object express js mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have array of `friends` inside users array , i need to get all `friends` of specific user by email that `approved` field is `true`

in nodejs i have user mongo schema

```js
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     username : {type: String , required :true},
     email : {type: String , required :true, unique: true, match: /.+\@.+\..+/},
     password : {type: String , required :true},
     friends : {type:[{username : String, approved: Boolean}]},
});
```

```json
[
  {
    "username": "ali",
    "email": "ali200@gmail,com",
    "password": "pdcjjfefmkadjakefkeofjafjafsfjsalnnryifajs",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "username": "gamal",
        "approved": true
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "username": "osama",
        "approved": false
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "username": "john",
        "approved": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i need to get array of `friends` object that `approved` field is `true` like this

```json
[
     {
        "id": "1",
        "username": "gamal",
        "approved": true
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "username": "john",
        "approved": true
      }

]
```

Code from comment:

```js
router.get("/getFriends", (req, res) => {
      var email = getEmailFromToken(req.header("Authorization"));
      User.findOne({
        email: email
      }).then((user) => res.status(200).send({
        friends: user.friends
      }));
```

Comment: What's the issue? Post the code that you have attempted.

Comment: i can get all friends but cant get freinds that has approved fields is true

Comment: router.get("/getFriends", (req, res) => {
  var email = getEmailFromToken(req.header("Authorization"));

  User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user) =>
  res.status(200).send({ friends: user.friends })
);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb
does this help. you can use the `eq` operator with the example in the link

Comment: Add the code in your question. Also, have a look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find

Comment: do you save your password as a plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using code, it can be done with

```
User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user) => {
  const friends = user.friends.filter((f) => f.approved);
  res.status(200).send({ friends });
});
```

or you can use query instead

```
User.agregate([
  {
    $match: {
      email: "ali200@gmail.com",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      friends: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$friends",
          as: "truelyFriend",
          cond: {
            $eq: ["$$truelyFriend.approved"],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]).then((user) => {
  res.status(200).send({ friends: user[0].friends });
});
```

mongo tester : [mongo-playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gDLxsGAs452)

Comment: Since `approved` is a boolean, you could simplify with [`cond: "$$truelyFriend.approved"`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lBvAje4Kx8i).

Comment: thats right, i miss that part. i forget the code i build is actually same with the query. Thank you.